# Leslie Matrix to predict human population.What are the advantages and disadvantages? Assumptions etc

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I am working with Leslie Matrices to predict population data in humans.

I would like to know what are the advantages and disadvantages? 
What assumptions a statistician has to make when predicting data using this method and what are the alternatives that can be used to make a better decision.

Can the Leslie method be modified to give better results?

I searched the web but information on this topic is rather fragmented everywhere.

Comment: As an application of mathematics, this might not be as suitable for Math.SE as for some other SE site.  Asking for "advantages and disadvantages" might be more dependent on the application "to predict population data in humans" than on reasoned mathematical argument.  In its current form there should be more context if you intended Readers to help with that mathematical reasoning side.

Comment: Here for example is a year old Question on Biology.SE that mentions population modeling, [Calculate growth rate of a population by Leslie matrix](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/72312/calculate-growth-rate-of-a-population-by-leslie-matrix)